# Kentico - Using value of added field (page type)

Tags: kentico

I need some help adding a field to a page type. I added it via "New Field". I set the field name to "ModalDataTarget".

[image: new field]

I inserted it in the page type transformation as {% ModalDataTarget %}.

[image: code]

I put the value in the text field.

[image: value]

It isn't populating with the value I add.

[image: return]

**Thanks in advance for any help!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which Web Part are you using? I would verify the column is returned in the query that is being run for it.

Which transformation type are you using? ASCX?  If so, you need to use <%#%> Format.

Comment: This was it! I didn't know about the Columns piece of it. The Web Part is "Pages data source" and looking in the columns field, the two fields I added weren't added in there. THANK YOU!

Answer (score 1):

You are calling macro method in transformation . You need to use [transformation methods](https://docs.kentico.com/k8/developing-websites/loading-and-displaying-data-on-websites/writing-transformations/reference-transformation-methods) instead:
try `<%#Eval<string>("modaldatatarget")%>`

Comment: Not necessarily. You can use macros if you switch the transformation type from ASCX to Text / XML.

Comment: I am using Text / XML type. The rest of the transformation uses Macros, so that is why I thought this would work...

Comment: Are you evaluating form values of other pages (e.g. in a repeater) or the current one?

Comment: Yeah. for Text/XML it should work! Make sure that everything spelled correctly and it is not null. Check the log as well.

Comment: Thank you both for your help. I missed the step of adding the fields to the Columns field in my web part. Appreciate it!